# How to change alerttemplate.xml in multilevel FARM

Tags: alert, xml, content-deployment, custom-alert-templates

I've been trying to deploy a new alerttemplate.xml for a specific site. But when I deployed it, I had someone me problems with alerts triggering for the entire FARM. All of sudden, all alerts stopped to work. So I did. Rollback to previous template, restart the fArm and all works. 
I have tow font-ends and tow app-servers.

My doubt are:

1. when I deploy a new template, it must be made for all servers in the farm or only to one app-server is enough?
2. should I have to restart all servers in the farm?

Answer (score 1):

here are the steps you have to followed

- Copy the updated alert template.xml on all servers.
- Open a command window in the 14 hive "TEMPLATE\XML" folder and run the following command:`stsadm -o updatealerttemplates -filename "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\XML\custom_alerttemplates.xml" -url "your site url"`
- Restart IIS on All servers
- Restart timer service on all server

No need to restart the server.